# Events sometimes not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which simply hides the main menu and brings up the next intended menu, it works exactly how I want it to but not always, the main menu does not hide so you end up with two overlapping menu's which bothers me.

I've shortened my code for simplicity, to only display the event for this particular menu.

```
$('.tileButton').click(function() {
    $('.bottomPiece', this).animate( { bottom: "+=50px", easing: "easeInOutBack" }, 'fast', function() {
        $('#mainMenu').hide("drop", {direction: "down", easing: "easeInOutBack"}, 1000, function() { 
            $('#backButton').fadeIn(300);
        });
    });
});


$('#media').click(function() {
    $('body').animate({ backgroundPositionX: "-=1000px", backgroundPositionY: "+=1000px"  }, 1500, function() {             
        $('#videoPlayerParent').show("drop", {direction: "down", easing: "easeInOutBack"}, 750);
    });
});
```

Since I'm still very green at this I'm not too sure but I suspect it to be because I'm calling two click events on the same item at once. But I'm not certain of this and the rate at which the problem occurs is very unpredictable, so testing is hard. Sometimes it'll work 20 times in a row just fine, but it usually happens when you least expect it.

Is this an issue with the double-click event or am I doing something else wrong?

I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate it. Lacks most functionality, it's a personal project made just to learn web coding. I added most of the code to a jsfiddle linked below, doesn't really show up exactly as it's supposed to. (New to Jsfiddle as well) But I just had the same problem occur in the JSFiddle too.

http://jsfiddle.net/9r545swy/2/

Talking specifically about the Media button in this case as that's the only page I added thus so far.

Image of what sometimes happens: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ccw8.jpg

The JSFiddle is a little messy so here's an actual live example:
http://flyingwhal.es/

(Works best on chrome as it's not optimized - at all)

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: For future reference, you will often be asked for the full code of any javascript + html related questions, because it's not easy to guess how does the structure look like. As someone said, provide a jsfiddle or simply include the html.

Comment: I think `$('.bottomPiece', this).animate()` should be `$('.bottomPiece').add(this).animate()` instead. Also instead of `"+=50px"` you can just pass the integer `50` in methods like `.animate()`.

Comment: install firebug(or somthing like Develper tool in firefox ((thanks to @Null)) ) and see if there is an error in your js,When there is an error, browser might stop the running the rest code.

Comment: @Masoud You don't need to install firebug to see javascript errors, every modern browser has developer tools.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I updated my post to showcase the actual error. My console does not display any errors aside from a video player error which I am aware of.

Comment: For the record, your fiddle is featuring the original javascript files loaded on top of the page which seem to replace any functionality written in JS Fiddle. It was still useful of course, but I had to poke around with it to make it "work".

Comment: Have you added your fix to flyingwhal.es yet, if not comment when you do. Honestly I think that's another problem that you described, I just didn't catch it or maybe confused it with a timing problem.

Comment: It was easy to reproduce the problem on your website now that you've described it, I think I was accidentally doing it when I tried to find out whether it's the fast clicking of back button causing the timing issues. Therefore my answer is not an answer, you should unmark it and answer yourself.

Comment: @null, sorry for my slower responses. I've added my own answer now but I would not have found it this easily without your help. :) I've made the changes on flyingwhal.es now, functions as intended. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and thank you @Null for helping me find the exact cause here. The real reason behind it happening was; I call .stop() on the .hover() event. So if you hovered your mouse out/in -side of the button right after clicking on the button the animation would obviously stop and the menu would not hide. This is why it happened at very unpredictable rates and just something that was hard to notice during interaction

<strike>So I changed my code for it to add a class during the animation, which if exists disables the hover event. The class is removed when the menu pops back up.</strike>

Found out that I can use use `{queue: false}` in the `.animation()` function.

It's always the little things.. but thanks a lot.

Comment: Mark it as an answer in case someone stumbles on it. ^^

Comment: I'm unable to for the next two days. I'll be sure to remember to do so when I can. :) `"You can accept your own answer in 2 days"`

Answer (score 1):

## Update:

The problem is *probably* a result of the bug Stella discovered, hence this is not an answer, but hopefully pointed things at the right direction.

#### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The problem was hard to catch, I think it occurs when you press back button very fast before the player animation events have completed, this code hits while the animations are still rolling and showing of the player haven't occured:

```
$('#mainMenu').hide();
$('#videoPlayerParent').hide();
```

But then this code hits after you've hidden it, because of timings:

```
$('#videoPlayerParent').show("drop", {direction: "down", easing: "easeInOutBack"}, 750);
```

Resulting in page overlapping as described by yourself.

Your solution focus will be making the timers consistent or implementing some sort of temporary disable like I did. There has to be a more elegant solution on which you can work on. I'm just pointing you in the right direction, hopefully.

## **My solution:**

**Load home menu function becomes:**

```
var loadHomeMenu = function () {
    $('#mainMenu').hide();
    //Disable the player as soon as you want to display the front page;
    $('#videoPlayerParent').addClass('disabled').hide();

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#mainMenu').show("drop", {
            direction: "down",
            easing: "easeInOutBack"
        }, 1000, function () {});
    },
    200);
};
```

**Media click function becomes:**

```
$('#media').click(function () {
        //Removing disabled when calling for the menu;
        $('#videoPlayerParent').removeClass('disabled');
        $('body').animate({
            backgroundPositionX: "-=1000px",
            backgroundPositionY: "+=1000px"
        }, 1500, function () {

            //Checking if the player wasn't disabled meanwhile, and if not executing the show animation;
            if (!$('#videoPlayerParent').hasClass('disabled')) {
                $('#videoPlayerParent').show("drop", {
                    direction: "down",
                    easing: "easeInOutBack"
                }, 750);
            }

        });
    });
```